# startView Angular UI Bootstrap DatePicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Could it be possible to set an attribute for the startview of the datepicker?

For example, could the datepicker be opened showing years instead of months?
This is described here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/jeUtVuztXzI for AngularStrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the next release (already landed in master) you will be able to use `datepicker-mode="day|month|year"` in order to initialize or programmatically set/watch the current mode of the datepicker.